# Apple Passbook(Wallet) device Registration not by app

Tags: ios, passbook, wallet

I'm trying to build up a web service to push discount information to end-users. My question is that I know we can push coupon by my own app but is there any possible way to avoid end-user installing our app? Is there any possible way that we only use web service to get device_library_identifier from our users to push notification to apple passbooks?

Very Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Pkpass files can be downloaded from web pages, attached to emails or loaded via QR code, for example. You don't need to use an app to deliver them.

When a .pkpass file is added to a user's wallet, it will register itself with your webService and you can then push updates to the pass.

This web service is outlined in Apple's documentation and covers what you need to record the pass:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/PassKit/Reference/PassKit_WebService/WebService.html

The section under "Update a Pass" in Apple's Wallet Overview, explains how this works in the context of a pass

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/PassKit_PG/Updating.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012195-CH5-SW1

Answer (score 0):

If normally you have new promotion to send coupon to customer time to time, you may start with member pass first so you can send link to download new coupon with notification to your member to load new coupon when they want without coming to your place to download new coupon.